# NSMutableArray data went nil when UITableView loads

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with populating the data from NSMutableArray to UITableView. In the `ViewDidLoad`, I did a network call which gets data from Parse and return an `NSMutableArray` called '`journalEntries`' then I copied the data in this array to the `NSMutableArray` variable called '`allEntries`'. I set a breakpoint here and verified that `_allEntries` has 4 objects (not nil). However, when it comes to `numberOfRowsInSection` method, `_allEntries.count` returns 4 but I set a breakpoint here and all the objects in `_allEntries` becomes `nil`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _allEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [MMDatabaseHelper getAllJournalEntries:^(NSMutableArray *journalEntries) {

        for (MMJournalEntry *entry in journalEntries)
             [_allEntries addObject:entry];
        // I set a breakpoint here and verified that _allEntries has 4 objects

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

This method below returns 4 but all the objects in the allEntries array are nil. They weren't nil in the viewDidLoad.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _allEntries.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MMJournalEntry *currentEntry = _allEntries[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**Edit 1**: The first screenshot is when the network call is done. The second is when it comes to the `numberOfRowsInSection` method

### [image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

**Edit 2**: This is `getAllJournalEntries` method

```
+(void) getAllJournalEntries:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *journalEntries))callback {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:JournalTable];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *entries, NSError *error) {
        if(entries != nil && entries.count > 0) {
            NSMutableArray *mainEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (PFObject *entry in entries) {
                //convert to journal entry...
                MMJournalEntry *je = [[MMJournalEntry alloc] init];
                je.objId = entry.objectId;
                je.textContent = entry[@"textContent"];
                je.createdByUserId = entry[@"createdByUserId"];
                je.cityStateName = entry[@"cityStateName"];
                je.lattitude = entry[@"lattitude"];
                je.longitude = entry[@"longitude"];
                je.lattitude = entry[@"lattitude"];
                je.tags = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[entry[@"tags"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
                je.numberOfHearts = entry[@"numberOfHearts"];

                [mainEntries addObject:je];
            }
            callback(mainEntries);
        }
        else
            callback(nil);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Elements of an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) cannot be `nil`. If you are seeing the "objects" in `_allEntries` as `nil`, there is something wrong with your debugger or your interpretation of its output.

Comment: Where's the declaration for `_allEntries`? If it's a @property of the viewController, maybe try `self.allEntries` instead? Shouldn't access the backing ivar directly anyway. Also if you're trying to access the entry for row #10 for example but you only have 5 entries, there is no value for that array index. Would be a good idea to confirm that entry exists anyway.

Comment: In cellForRow... NSLog your _allEntries object.  It's probably nil (will log as `(null)`).  It's illegal for there to be nil entries in an NSArray.

Comment: What queue does `getAllJournalEntries:` call its completion handler on? It's easy to imagine that `reloadData` wouldn't work from a background queue. In that case your assumption that `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is called *after* `-viewDidLoad` wouldn't necessarily stand up.

Comment: I added the `getAllJournalEntries` method

Comment: If your instance of _allEntries a property with a set weak attribute? Because when you test this on a simulator this works but in a dispositive a weak reference gets deallocated between methods.

Comment: it's strong `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allEntries;`

Comment: Can you show the definition of your `MMJournalEntry` object - in particular its property declarations - it looks like they are being released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time trying to fix this bug, I finally fixed it. Thanks to Paulw11's comment, the problem is with `MMJournalEntry`. All of the properites in this class were declared `weak` instead of `strong`. My teammate wrote this class so I didn't check. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

As you receive an `NSMutableArray` from Parse, why you don't simply copy it on an `NSArray`? You should redeclare your allEntries property and you don't need the `forin` loop.

```
_allEntries = journalEntries.copy;
```

As `NSArray` is not mutable, it will never lose values.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no alloced cell that use @"Cell" as Indentifier.

The method:

`[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

will return `nil`

Comment: As of iOS6 you no longer need to worry about this - if no cell exists it gets created for you.

Comment: ... indeed that's the difference between the class form of `dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:` and the modern form of `dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:forIndexPath:`. The latter *guarantees it'll return a cell* (and, possibly, caches better, because it has more information).

Comment: @mc01. OK... I really dont know that.. Or maybe the `journalEntries` is released when call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?...But I remembered that NSMutableArray's `addObject` retain the object.